# Why does “/proc/config.gz” show wrong configuration?

Tags: linux-kernel, configuration, android, cross-compilation

The file `/proc/config.gz` isn't updated when I rebuild kernel with changed configuration (from `make menuconfig`). For instance, I have rebuilt kernel with `BLK_DEV_IO_TRACE` which works fine but `config.gz` is still showing `# CONFIG_BLK_DEV_IO_TRACE is not set`. Isn't the `.config` file in the root directory of kernel source which is included in kernel binary when we enable `CONFIG_IKCONFIG`?

And BTW `config.gz` shows `CONFIG_IKCONFIG=y` while in actual it is `CONFIG_IKCONFIG=m`.

I'm using Android NDK standalone GCC toolchain to build [this kernel](https://github.com/franciscofranco/mido) (3.18 arm64).

**NOTE:**

Just to clarify, as it's causing confusion, I'm sure my new kernel is running with new configuration. I've enabled a long list of changes to my default configuration which are working now, a number of userspace programs depend on these configurations:

```
CONFIG_IKCONFIG=m
CONFIG_IKCONFIG_PROC=y
CONFIG_VETH=y
CONFIG_MODULES=y
CONFIG_MODULE_UNLOAD=y
CONFIG_NFS_FS=m
CONFIG_NFS_V2=m
CONFIG_NFS_V3=m
CONFIG_NFS_V4=m
CONFIG_NFS_V4_1=y
CONFIG_NFS_V4_2=y
CONFIG_NFSD=m
CONFIG_NFSD_V3=y
CONFIG_NFSD_V4=y
CONFIG_NFSD_V4_SECURITY_LABEL=y
CONFIG_KEYS_DEBUG_PROC_KEYS=y
CONFIG_OVERLAY_FS=m
CONFIG_UTS_NS=y
CONFIG_USER_NS=y
CONFIG_PID_NS=y
CONFIG_NET_CLS_CGROUP=m
CONFIG_CGROUP_NET_CLASSID=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_CGROUP=m
CONFIG_NETFILTER_NETLINK=m
CONFIG_ISO9660_FS=m
CONFIG_SQUASHFS=m
CONFIG_UDF_FS=m
CONFIG_UNIX_DIAG=m
CONFIG_PSTORE=y
CONFIG_FANOTIFY=y
CONFIG_FANOTIFY_ACCESS_PERMISSIONS=y
CONFIG_DEBUG_FS=y
CONFIG_FTRACE=y
CONFIG_BLK_DEV_IO_TRACE=y
```

`config.gz` shows `Linux/arm64 3.18.71 Kernel Configuration` while the current is `Linux/arm64 3.18.140 Kernel Configuration`. <strike>Also it doesn't matches with any of the 16 `*defconfig` files in `arch/arm64/configs/`.</strike> There are 185 differences (88 additions, 97 drops) between actual config and `config.gz`. Initially I used `arch/arm64/configs/franco_mido_defconfig`; the one provided by custom kernel developer.

Comment: Have you rebooted and verified that the new kernel you just compiled is actually running?

Comment: @telcoM it's an Android phone, can't have multiple kernels. As I mentioned, BLK_DEV_IO_TRACE is working fine, I can trace I/O operations. Also the problem persists for over a year almost, not occuring first time.

Comment: `/proc/config.gz` is the currently running kernel's configuration. It isn't going to be affected by whatever random kernel you build.

Comment: @muru I cross-compiled the kernel on Ubuntu PC. Transfered new kernel image to phone. Rebooted my phone to recovery mode. Flashed the kernel to `boot.img`. Restarted phone. And I'm dead sure new kernel is running. I have been doing this for years.

Comment: I see, sorry I misunderstood. Do you have a diff of the config from what you had built?

Comment: @muru let me get back to PC and I'll share.

Comment: @muru see the [list](https://pastebin.com/L82LbMuz) of 185 differences. [This](https://pastebin.com/ku6bfMTq) one is easy to compare.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I should have done more research prior to posting this question, but I thought might be I was missing something. For reference, the problem reveals to be specific to my kernel source. Custom kernel developer applied a [patch](https://github.com/franciscofranco/mido/commit/c9ea8d1f6bb5f9cd0c30053e98c2130b5a9499ab) to always include an older configuration in kernel binary. So this should be undone (considering the risks, if any):

```
ifeq ($(CONFIG_MACH_XIAOMI_MIDO),y)
    $(obj)/config_data.gz: arch/arm64/configs/mido_defconfig FORCE
else ifeq ($(CONFIG_MACH_XIAOMI_TISSOT),y)
    $(obj)/config_data.gz: arch/arm64/configs/tissot_defconfig FORCE
else
    $(obj)/config_data.gz: $(KCONFIG_CONFIG) FORCE
endif
```

Answer (score 1):

The kernel option that produces `/proc/config.gz` is IKCONFIG_PROC, not just IKCONFIG. And IKCONFIG_PROC cannot be a module.

Also, note that there are `kernel/configs/android-base.config`  and `kernel/configs/android-recommended.config`. These may be used to override some kernel configuration settings, see https://lore.kernel.org/linux-arm-kernel/1466708235-28593-1-git-send-email-robh@kernel.org/

If your kernel compilation procedure uses a command like this (an example mentioned in the Linux-ARM-Kernel list post linked above)

```
make ARCH=arm multi_v7_defconfig android-base.config android-recommended.config
```

then those files are indeed being used. And `android-base.config` includes setting both `CONFIG_IKCONFIG` and `CONFIG_IKCONFIG_PROC` to `y`.

Are you sure your toolchain is not doing something like

```
make ARCH=arm <oldconfig or some other config target> android-base.config
```

before actually starting to build your kernel?

Comment: IKCONFIG **enables the complete Linux kernel ".config" file contents to be saved in the kernel. This information can be extracted from the kernel image file with the script scripts/extract-ikconfig.** IKCONFIG_PROC just **enables access to the kernel configuration file through /proc/config.gz**, it doesn't affect the contents of `.config` file, which my actual point of question is. I'm dead sure my new kernel is running with new configuration. See the edit to OP. I have only one file `kernel/configs/tiny.config` with a total 4 configurations. So it's definitely not being used.

Comment: I'm sure that you're sure you've done everything correctly. That does not remove the possibility of, for example, your toolchain or perhaps buggy bootloader or rootkitted firmware playing tricks on you. Also, since you have CONFIG_IKCONFIG=m, does the `ikconfig.ko` module actually exist? Does `cat /proc/version`  show the right or the wrong version? You may have just uncovered signs of a possible factory-installed rootkit on your Xiaomi Redmi Note 4.

Comment: It's not `ikconfig.ko` but `configs.ko`, and yes it exists. `cat /proc/version` shows exactly what I expect: `Linux version 3.18.140-FrancoKernel (irfan@irfan-Inspiron-5521) (gcc version 4.9.x 20150123 (prerelease) (GCC) ) #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Jun 28 00:02:54 PKT 2019`

Comment: I think I have found the culprit code. I'll have to undo this commit: https://github.com/franciscofranco/mido/commit/c9ea8d1f6bb5f9cd0c30053e98c2130b5a9499ab

Comment: Note that the commit text says: "Userspace reads /proc/config.gz and spits out an error message after boot finishes when it doesn't like the kernel's configuration. " Unless you're customizing the userspace too (or further updates to the userspace code have removed the checks), it looks like you might have to make `/proc/config.gz` tell lies in order to keep the userspace parts of your phone's software happy.

Comment: On stock kernels `IKCONFIG_PROC` and even `IKCONFIG` are disabled at all AFA I have seen. And SELinux policy won't allow non-privileged apps (and most of the privileged processes) to read `/proc/config.gz`. Adding one more layer of protection, I build it as an un-loadable module, leaving least chances of breaking userspace. Anyway thanks for help.